# Docker compose invalid top-level property "name"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up my docker project name, and according to documentation there should be the docker compose file top-level property 'name' to do so, but I can't figure out how to use it.

I found references at the end of [The Compose application model](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#the-compose-application-model) section and in the specific [Name top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element) section, but none of the two have an example and I still get an error when trying to run `docker-compose up -d`

##### docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3.3"

name: "project-name"

services:
    # ...
```

##### The error

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "name". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, secrets, configs, and extensions starting with "x-".

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the compose-spec, you need a tool that parses that spec (like `docker compose` with a space) and you shouldn't be specifying a version. If you are parsing the file with an older version of `docker-compose` or a tool that doesn't use the spec, these newer fields won't work and you'll likely see it fall back to version 1 without a version field.

With `version: "3.3"`, that expects the format defined in [the version 3 documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).

Comment: That sounds helpful. However, according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/ , the current version of the specification should apply from docker engine release `19.03.0` on. I have `20.10.11` (on Debian Bullseye), but `name` does still not work for me, neither with nor (as recommended) without a `version` declaration in the compose file. Docker documentation is a mess.

Comment: Apparently, the "top-level name element" functionality of Docker's own implementation of the [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element) is simply totally broken: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9530

Comment: @LutzPrechelt these are the sorts of issues that come from removing the version from a file where multiple tools may behave differently. But that's the path that Docker took. The docs site is up on GitHub, so you can push PRs for errors there.